# Skip line after a pick with chosen jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using chosen jQuery for multiple select. How can I skip a line after I select one value ?

```
<select class="form-control chosen-select" multiple  name="seguro_medico[]" >
  <option></option>
  <?php 
    foreach($seguro_medico as $row) { 
      echo '<option value="'.$row->medical_insurance.'">'.$row->medical_insurance.'</option>';
    }
  ?>
</select>

// jQuery
$(".chosen-select").chosen({
  no_results_text: "Oops, nada encontrado por : "
});
```

Comment: share `$seguro_medico` in html format , or better make a live demo ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using CSS.

Use:

```
.chosen-choices li {
    display: block;
    width: 100% !important;
}
```

Comment: it's not working. The result of your css is after one select the line is breaked indeed , but the second select returns to the first line.

Comment: @Diasline did you put `!important` as I have edited in my answer?

Comment: @Diasline sorry my bad! just remove `.search-field` from the CSS Selector.

Comment: that's work like a charm thank you.  I accept it. How can i  adjut the text frame according the width  value .?